# Callback to parent window from child in IE?

Tags: javascript

I have the code below which opens a child window and the child has a callback function to the parent to close the child window which is called with onLoad in the child.

The code works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Parent JS

```
    var wnd = null;
    function openWnd() 
    {
        wnd = window.open('http://www.example.com');
    }

    function closeWnd()
    {
        if (wnd != null) {
            wnd.close();
        }   
    }
```

Child JS

```
    function parent_callback() 
    {
        setTimeout(function (){ window.opener.closeWnd();}, 3000);
    }
```

Why is IE always a pain for developers M$ needs to pull its fingure out :)

Thanks

Comment: How does your closePdf function look like?
Try a window.opener.setTimeout(..., 3000); instead

Comment: @Bengt - Sorry closePdf is closeWnd it was my mistake. I need the child to do a callback so that I know the child content has been loaded.

Comment: did window.opener.setTimeout work?

Comment: As written, your code works in IE 8. I have created two files: `parent.html` (which calls `openWnd("child.html")`) and `child.html` (which calls `parent_callback`). You will need to provide more details if anyone is to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Your child window is calling a function `closePDF()` but your parent window defines `closeWnd()`. I can't see how that would work in *any* browser yet you say it works in Chrome and FF? Maybe if you post some more of your code, e.g., the onload that you mention, or the `closePDF()` if there actually is one.

Comment: Yes it was my mistake I have edited my post, still not working in IE.